# Generate PCL from PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, printer-control-language

What is the best way to generate a PCL output file from an existing PDF file in java?

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "best".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much you want to invest, and how robust the solution needs to be. For quick and dirty, you can print from Adobe Acrobat to a file, using a PCL driver (look, mom, no Java ...).

The [Java Print Service API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing.fm2.html) can process PDF. Use StreamPrintService and write the stream to a file, using PCL for the output format.

If you need to have more control over the content, maybe modify it or add to it, you can use a PDF parser ([this one](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/), for instance) and print the resulting HTML from a browser that your application starts, by adding some Javascript, for example.

Comment: Do you have experience with the PDF or PS input flavours for this?

Answer (score 1):

The StreamPrintService from JDK 6 does only support PS.  I am still searching for a StreamPrintService which supports PCL.

Answer (score 0):

We capture PCL generated from Acrobat printing a PDF to a PCL driver and redirect as input to our Windows console PCLXForm program.  With a custom script, we can "stream edit" the PCL.  We can extract the address block text for address correction, insert the corrected text, add the Intelligent Mail Barcode, 2-D barcodes, sort the documents, batch them by page count, change tray assignments, merge with other documents, etc.  The product required is PCLTool SDK - Option V at www.pagetech.com